# How to get current EAR location programmatically with JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, seam, ear

Does anyone know how to get programmatically the absolute path in the filesystem for an EAR deployed in JBoss, from Java code within that same EAR?

I need this because I want to copy some files that are inside the EAR to another part of the filesystem, on deploy-time.

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do this way.
EAR has a service MyService, where I work with EAR contents:

```
import org.jboss.system.ServiceControllerMBean;
import org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport;

public class MyService extends ServiceMBeanSupport {

    public void workWithEar() 
    {
        ServiceControllerMBean serviceController = (ServiceControllerMBean) MBeanProxy.get(
                    ServiceControllerMBean.class,
                    ServiceControllerMBean.OBJECT_NAME, server);
        // server is ServiceMBeanSupport member

        ClassLoader cl = serviceController.getClass().getClassLoader();

        String path = cl.getResource("META-INF/jboss-service.xml").getPath()
        InputStream file = cl.getResourceAsStream("META-INF/jboss-service.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: I could use a simpler way, since the class where I need that path, I'm within the EAR that holds the WAR that contains the files I want to copy.

So, I just needed 1 line of code:
String path = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("my_war_filename.war").getPath();

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

you can do you "System.getProperty()" here is the [link](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossProperties) for other the properties you can used

ex:

```
String jBossPath = System.getProperty("jboss.server.base.dir")
```

result

```
"/Users/ALL_THE_PATH/JBoss_7-1/standelone"
```

After you just need to  add `"/deployments/YOUR_PROJECT_EAR/..."`

Comment: A simple and clean solution, very usefull!

Answer (score 3):

To get the `ServletContext` from Seam, you can do:

```
ServletLifecycle.getCurrentServletContext()
```

which is available as soon as Seam has created the `applicationContext`. And then `getRealPath("/")` works fine for root context's deployment folder. Any folder structure within context root can be reached.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite fiddly, but you can do this by querying the JBoss `MainDeployer` MBean. The MBean is found at `jboss.system:service=MainDeployer`, and has a JMX operation `listDeployments`. This returns a collection of `DeploymentInfo` objects, one of which will be your EAR deployment. That DeploymentInfo has a `url` property which is a `file://` URL describing your deployment directory.

Nice, eh? You can use the raw JMX API to do this, but Spring provides a much nicer mechanism, using a `MBeanProxyFactoryBean` to expose an instance of `MainDeployerMBean`.

I'd like to find a simpler way, but that's the best I've found so far.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It didn't work in my case however: I'm using SeamFramework together with JBoss, and I need this code to run from a method that is annotated as @Observer("org.jboss.seam.postInitialization"), which is called when a Seam application starts. At this point I would get a MainDeployerMBean that reported: 0 deployed EARs, 0 incomplete and 0 waiting for deploy...

Answer (score 1):

Are these resources mapped or made available under a web path (within a WAR)?

If so, you could attempt to use [`ServletContext.getRealPath()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)) to translate the virtual path to the real/filesystem path.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It didn't work in my case however: As I stated in another comment, I'm using this in Seam startup. I couldn't find a way to get a ServletContext at this point (it would return as null).